# Initialize listbox in c# with a list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to initialize **value** and **memberDisplay** of my list box using the output of this code :

Here is my code :

```
    public List<showMaterialGroup> ShowSubGroup()
    {
        List<showMaterialGroup> q = (from i in dbconnect.tblMaterialGroups.AsEnumerable()
                                     where i.tenderId == _tenderId 

                                     select new showMaterialGroup()
                                         {
                                             id = i.id.ToString(),
                                             title = i.title,
                                             documentnumber = ReturnDocNumber(i.tenderId),

                                         }).ToList();
        return q;
    }
```

Here i call the function :

```
   txtgroup.DisplayMember = objtender.ShowSubGroup();
        txtgroup.ValueMember = objtender.ShowSubGroup();
```

So how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `txtgroup` is a `ListBox`, even though it's sorta named like a `TextBox` might be named. You can't assign a list to the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Assign the list as the `DataSource`, then use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties to specify which field should be displayed to the user and used as the actual value for the item in the list, respectively.

Try this instead:

```
txtgroup.DataSource = objtender.ShowSubGroup();

txtgroup.DisplayMember = "title";
txtgroup.ValueMember = "id";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about what these properties are supposed to do. [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are strings. They identify which properties of the items in the control's [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should represent the display content or value for each item.

Try this:

```
txtgroup.DataSource = objtender.ShowSubGroup();
txtgroup.DisplayMember = "title";
txtgroup.ValueMember = "id";
```